# Rails ujs for partial DOM replacement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

My front-end structure is like below:

```
<div id='item-list'>
  # List of items to be replaced every time
</div>

<form>
  <submit/>
</form>
```

The idea is that, every time when the `submit` button is clicked, my JS would send AJAX request, and the server would return an HTML partial for the `item-list`, and in my front-end, the `item-list` would be replaced with the ajax return.

However, since there're also some use of UJS in my `item-list`, the bindings no longer works after the replacement.

I believe it's the problem that the UJS code didn't execute when the replacement happens. I want to ask how to force the execution of UJS code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The chances to be something wrong with UJS are very small. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/ an use it when you bind your events.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [delegate](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) your event bindings from an element which is always going to be present on your page (typically `document`):

```
$(document).on("submit", ".element", function(){
  //stuff
});
```

The problem you have is that Javascript only works with elements in the actual DOM. It doesn't, nor can it work with, elements which are appended *after* the DOM has been loaded

This means you have to bind the javascript events to elements which will always be present in the DOM, and delegate from them

--

That's the best I can do with what you've sent so far  - if you give more context, I'll be able to provide a richer answer